# autofs can't mount a remote dir with sshfs on the host with deprecated key algorithm

Tags: ssh, sshfs, automount, autofs, hostkey

Here is my configuration:

/etc/auto.master

```
/mnt/10       /etc/auto.10 uid=0,gid=0,--ghost
```

/etc/auto.10

```
root -fstype=fuse,allow_other,follow_symlinks,ssh_command=/etc/ssh/sshpass.10.sh    :sshfs\#root@10.28.0.10\:/root
```

Because the remote device is an appliance and it doesn't have an ability to save a key to do a passwordless login, I have to pass a password with an sshpass command. For that I used an ssh_command= parameter

/etc/ssh/sshpass.10.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -f /etc/ssh/sshpass.10 ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-dss $*
```

I had to use -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-dss in my ssh command config, because that appliance has an old openssh server. The device is out of production and doesn't do any more updates. When I ssh to it from my updated computer, it complains about no matching algorithms:

```
Unable to negotiate with 10.28.0.10 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss
```

So, with a regular ssh, I have to do:

```
 ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-dss root@10.28.0.10
```

So, I did in /etc/ssh/sshpass.10.sh ssh setup file, as I stated above.

And the last file, has an ssh root password in it on the first line of a file with a line break.
/etc/ssh/sshpass.10
i.e.:

```
password
```

I am not able to show a line break here, though and of course, this is not the password, that I am using.

#### The problem:

When I try to go to the path, that was configured in these files, I can  get to:
/mnt/10
and root folder appears there. I try to go inside of it, I get an error:

```
Can't access '/mnt/10/fsshroot/': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out.
I tried to directly run:

```
sudo sshfs root@10.28.0.10:/root /tmp/10/ -o reconnect,allow_other,follow_symlinks,ssh_command='ssh HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-dss'
```

and it gave me an error:

```
read: Connection reset by peer
```

So, it didn't work. I started looking for a way to fix it and found out, that in order to do it, I have to configure 2 lines in:
/etc/ssh/ssh_config

```
Host 10.28.0.10
    HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss
```

Then, I removed:

```
 -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-dss
```

from:
/etc/ssh/sshpass.10.sh
to make it like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -f /etc/ssh/sshpass.10 ssh $*
```

Then, after restarting autofs service, it started working. My
/mnt/10/root
started displaying contents.

Comment: Thank you for posting how you ended-up resolving this. A stranger on the online is really grateful.